# I have two question in python grammar. for loop and while loop

Tags: python

```
from typing import List  

def dailyTemperatures(temperatures: List[int]) -> List[int]:
    temp_count = len(temperatures)
    ans = [0]*temp_count
    
    stack = []
    idx_stack = []
    
    for idx in range(temp_count-1,-1,-1): // first point
      temperature = temperatures[idx]
      
      last_temp_idx = 0
      while stack: // second point
        last_temp = stack[-1]
        last_temp_idx = idx_stack[-1]
        if last_temp <= temperature:
          stack.pop()
          idx_stack.pop()
        else:
          break
      
      if len(stack) == 0:
        stack.append(temperature)
        idx_stack.append(idx)
        ans[idx] = 0
        continue
        
      stack.append(temperature)
      idx_stack.append(idx)
      ans[idx] = last_temp_idx-idx
    
    return ans
```

I have two question. I've just started learning python.
I googled but couldn't find an answer.
first point > (temp_count-1,-1,-1)
I'm not sure what this sentence means.
Does this mean decrement by one? Why are there two -1?

second point > while stack:
Does this sentence mean that when stack is empty is operate?

Comment: 1) Comments in python use ```#```. 2) ```temp_count-1,-1,-1``` tells the ```range``` to go from ```temp_count-1``` to ```-1``` backwards, due to negative ```step``` ```-1```. Maybe you should first try printing ```for i in range(5,-1,-1): print(i)``` and see the output. ```empty``` lists have False values. It is telling python to loop while ```stack``` has at least one elements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `(temp_count-1,-1,-1)`

`range` has 3 parameters: `start`, `stop`, `step`. In your function, those 3 parametres are `temp_count-1`, `-1`, `-1` respectively. This tells `range` function to generate functions with the first element as `temp_count-1`, till the last element: `0`, going backwards: `-1`.

Let's take a simple example:

```
>>> temp_count=6
>>> for i in range(temp_count-1,-1,-1):
        print(i)    
5
4
3
2
1
0
```

Here, `temp_count` has a value: 6. Doing `temp_count-1` is `6 - 1 = 5`. The `stop` value is `-1`. Since range always generates numbers till `stop - 1`, it will be `-1 - (-1) = -1 + 1 = 0`. So the last number is 0.

The `step` parameters orders it to go backwards. That is why you see `5, 4..... 0`.

---

> `while stack`

`stack` is an empty list. Empty lists have `False` values in python. For a list to be `Truthy`, it must have atleast one element.

So

```
while stack
```

will keep looping until there is no element in the list.
Example:

```
>>> stack=[1,2,3]
>>> while stack:
        stack.pop()
3
2
1
```

`pop()` method removes the last element from the list an returns it. This shows that:

```
3 ---> removed from the list and returned
stack = [2, 1]

2 ---> removed from the list and returned
stack = [1]

1 ---> removed from the list and returned
stack = []

#===== Stop =====
```

When the list had elements, it had truthy value, but when it became empty, it becomes : `while False` and the while loop exits

Comment: @DavidKim No problem. :)

Answer (score 1):

1. Range function (temp_count-1, -1, -1): Range function in python work as follows.

- `range(start, stop, step)`.
- For example, `for i in range(1, 10, 2)` will iterate with for values `1, 3, 5, 7, 9`.

2. `while stack` means iterate until the value of variable `stack` is not `None`.

Answer (score 1):

**`range((temp_count-1,-1,-1))`**

`range()` function accepts three arguments start, stop and step. The above starts with `temp_count-1` and ends when the value becomes -1 decrementing the value by -1 after each iteration. Refer this: [range](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#range)

**`while stack`**

This means as long as the stack is not empty, keep looping.
Refer this: [Truth value testing](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=range#truth-value-testing)